# How to programmatically setup a <security-constraint> in Servlets 3.x?

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-3.0

In my current web application I am trying to get rid of web.xml and I have not been able to properly setup the security constraint that forces all requests to the application to use HTTPS.

```
<security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
     <web-resource-name>all</web-resource-name>
     <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <user-data-constraint>
     <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
  </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

How can I turn the above web.xml configuration snippet in servlet 3.x configuration code that does the same thing?

**UPDATE**

I want the constraint to apply to every servlet, filter, and static resource in application, the examples I have seen online so far show to attach a security constraint to a servlet, but I want the security constraint attached to the web app. In the xml snippet above you see that it does not reference any specific servlet

Comment: We are migrating our Spring XML based configuration to class based configuration. I am also looking for equivalent java configuration for the above xml configuration (web.xml).  If you have already, please share.

Answer (score 14):

I believe you are looking for the `@ServletSecurity` annotation

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/*")
@ServletSecurity(value = @HttpConstraint(transportGuarantee = TransportGuarantee.CONFIDENTIAL))
public class SomeServlet extends HttpServlet { ... }
```

Or with `ServletRegistration` in a `ServletContainerInitializer` (or anywhere you have access to a `ServletContext`)

```
ServletRegistration.Dynamic dynamic = context.addServlet("someServlet", SomeServlet.class);
dynamic.addMapping("/*");
HttpConstraintElement httpConstraintElement = new HttpConstraintElement(TransportGuarantee.CONFIDENTIAL);
ServletSecurityElement servletSecurityElement = new ServletSecurityElement(httpConstraintElement);
dynamic.setServletSecurity(servletSecurityElement);
```

Comment: I want the constraint on all resources not on a specific as I want this constraint to apply to .css, .js, .jsp, .html no matter what I only want https.

Comment: @ams Looking at the `ServletContext` interface, I could not find a way.

Comment: It seems that sometimes the spec designers forget things in their specs.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do this for a project by configuring the glassfish domain security:

1. Create a new security domain, in this example call it: FooRealm
2. Add users w (or w/o) passwords to FooRealm
3. Add each user to "GroupFoo"

That covers your glassfish config, here is your web.xml:

```
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>SecurityConstraint</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Everything</web-resource-name>
        <description>Everything</description>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <description>UserAuthenticationConstraint</description>
        <role-name>GroupFoo</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>FooRealm</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/Login.jsp</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/LoginError.html</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you after deploy to  JBoss or WildFly  (Undertow based server ) there is a solution.

add ServletContainerInitializer or WebApplicationInitializer to you project .

`onStartup(Set<Class<?>> c, ServletContext ctx)` or `onStartup(ServletContext ctx)`

```
io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletContextImpl servletContextImpl = (ServletContextImpl) ctx;
io.undertow.servlet.api.Deployment deployment = (DeploymentImpl) servletContextImpl.getDeployment();
DeploymentInfo deploymentInfo = deployment.getDeploymentInfo();
deploymentInfo.addSecurityConstraint(Servlets.securityConstraint()
                    .addRoleAllowed("*")
                    .addWebResourceCollections(Servlets.webResourceCollection().addUrlPattern("/*")));

//auth-mode 
deploymentInfo.setLoginConfig(Servlets.loginConfig("BASIC", null));
//deploymentInfo.setLoginConfig(Servlets.loginConfig("SPNEGO", "SPNEGO"));

deploymentInfo.addSecurityRole("*");
deploymentInfo.setSecurityDisabled(false);

....
 //ur Servlets go here
 ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = ctx.addServlet("rwtServlet", "org.eclipse.rap.rwt.engine.RWTServlet");

 servlet.addMapping("/rap");

 ctx.addListener("org.eclipse.rap.rwt.engine.RWTServletContextListener");
```

*note:* make sure to add `undertow-servlet` as compile time time dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.undertow</groupId>
    <artifactId>undertow-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.30.Final</version>
</dependency>
```