# Spring Boot HTTPS and redirect

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot, security-constraint

I am using Spring STS with Pivotal 3.1 server (ports 8080 and 8443)
I have also a separate tomcat 7 instance on the box which runs
on 80 and 443.

I use Spring Boot 1.2.4 release.

I would like the application to automatically redirect all requests 
to https - I am not using embedded tomcat instance.

Previously using spring I had  tag in web.xml 
and it was working just fine.

How can I achieve the same using spring boot please ?

Thanks,
Adrian

Comment: are you using spring-security in the project?

Comment: No - I am using Apache Shiro for that (maven and vaadin 7.4) Recently moved it from Spring to Spring Boot.

Comment: Check the pivotal server configuration located at .../sts-bundle/pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.1.1.RELEASE/base-instance/conf

Comment: I have a tested and tried tomcat 7 server instance up and running. It works fine when deploying old war file which has web.xml with <security-constraint> in it. So it is not a server configuration problem.

Comment: seems similar answer can help https://stackoverflow.com/a/38829838/1851289

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you were using Spring Security you could do this by adding `security.require_ssl=true` to your application.properties as mentioned in [the Spring Boot reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-enable-https). If you customize the Spring Security configuration, then you will want to have something like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            // ...
            .requiresChannel()
                .anyRequest().requiresSecure();
    }
}
```

Since you aren't using Spring Security and you are using a war file the easiest way is to create a web.xml with the following in it:

**src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee                       http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>all</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
</web-app>
```

Using a web.xml is necessary because there is no way to setup a security constraint of the entire application programatically. You can find some details on that in [How to programmatically setup a <security-constraint> in Servlets 3.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19297796/how-to-programmatically-setup-a-security-constraint-in-servlets-3-x)

Comment: Thanks very much Rob!
A bit of shame the API does not support this though.

Comment: @Rob how do I go about doing this in a Java configuration way in Spring Boot, if I did not want to use web.xml?