# Jetty Redirect HTTP to HTTPS using Rewrite

Tags: java, jsp, url-rewriting, jetty

I have an embedded Jetty Server and I want to direct request from http://localhost:8080/ to https://localhost:4433/ how do I do that? I tried this:

```
    // Set up rewriting (HTTP -> HTTPS)
    RewriteHandler rewrite = new RewriteHandler();

    RedirectPatternRule redirect = new RedirectPatternRule();
    redirect.setPattern("http://localhost:8080/*");
    redirect.setLocation("https://localhost:4433/");  
    rewrite.addRule(redirect);
```

And added it within my handler, but it doesn't work. I know rules like

```
    RewriteHandler rewrite = new RewriteHandler();

    RedirectPatternRule redirect = new RedirectPatternRule();
    redirect.setPattern("/redirect/*");
    redirect.setLocation("/redirected");  
    rewrite.addRule(redirect);
```

work 100%, but is there a way to match the full URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `RewriteHandler` only works with paths.

Not schemes, hosts, or ports.

You can use the [`SecuredRedirectHandler`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/handler/SecuredRedirectHandler.html) built into the `jetty-server` artifact since Jetty 9.2.  (Be sure you have a valid `HttpConfiguration` setup for both of your connectors)

.. or ..

You could use the Servlet constraints to enforce it to be confidential.

See [`buildConstraintSecurityHandler()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33261787/775715) in the answer to [how to programatically enforce security-constraint in web.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33175879/jetty-how-to-programatically-enforce-security-constraint-in-web-xml)

Answer (score 0):

A more general approach that is not specific to Jetty is to return a 301 with a new URL:

```
GET /path/location.html HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
```

gets turned into

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://example.com/path/location.html
```

This can be done in Jetty and most server frameworks by simply setting the response status and adding the location header in a filter if you dont want the resource to be accessible through plain-text http.