# How to migrate <security-constraint> in web.xml to spring class based configuration (WebApplicationInitializer)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, web.xml

In our current XML based configuration, we have below configuration in web.xml to disable non-ssl(HTTP) protocol access.

```xml
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>SecureConnection</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

I am migrating this XML based configuration to Java configuration. How to setup this configuration in Spring WebApplicationInitializer. I have found [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19297796/how-to-programmatically-setup-a-security-constraint-in-servlets-3-x)  posted by @ams years ago, but it is without complete/proper answer. How can I achieve this using Java configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the below solution to access request only through SSL(HTTPS) and disable non-ssl access(HTTP) after gone through the Spring **HttpSecurity** class. Tested this and working fine. Need to configure this overridden **configure()** method of **WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter**

```
http.requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresSecure();
```

Answer (score 0):

You create a [`WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.html) and configure the [`HttpSecurity`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html)

You should go through the documentation of [`HttpSecurity`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html) to figure out the right configurations you need to apply.

Basic example:

```
 @Configuration
 @EnableWebSecurity
 public class OpenIDLoginConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) {
                http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").hasRole("USER").and().openidLogin()
                                .permitAll();
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
                auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                                .withUser("https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=lmkCn9xzPdsxVwG")
                                .password("password").roles("USER");
        }
 }
```

Further reading : https://www.baeldung.com/java-config-spring-security